# What is the official name of the simple stepwise CDF estimation

Tags: estimation, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a set of observed one-dimensional independent data set: X[1...N].

What is the official name of the simple estimation of CDF function with stepwise function P(x[i]) == i / N

Comment: To follow up on @Scortchi's excellent answer, there's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) that may help.

Comment: @Glen_b: add it as a link in the answer.

Comment: Minutest of minute points, but this _is_ about terminology. I'd say step function here. The word "stepwise" has quite different associations, indicating a method of predictor selection in model fitting. Although using the word "stepwise" is unlikely to cause real confusion, "step" is the better word here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's usually called the 'empirical cumulative distribution function', typically abbreviated to 'empirical CDF', or sometimes it's called just the '[empirical distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)'.